# Array calculation in R

Tags: arrays, r, row

I have the following table:

```
        ID  Measure1  Measure2     XO      X1      x2      x3       x4     x5   Flag
Customer 1        30         2  item1   item1   item5   item2   item12  item4     1
Customer 1        30         2  item2   item1   item5   item2   NA       NA       3
Customer 1        30         2  item4   item2   item5   item2   item12  item4     5
```

where flag is an indicator of the case where XO(atual)  equals one of x1-x5(predicted) and returns its position.

The next steps I would like to perform is to perform a type of cumulative distribution of correct hits that would be indicated by 5 new columns(flag1-flag5), the end product would be something like this:

```
        ID  Measure1  Measure2  Flag1  Flag2  Flag3  Flag4  Flag5
Customer 1        30         2      1      1      2      2      3
```

which in this example means:

- Item1 is predicted at x1  ,therefore flag1=1
- In the second column x2 I have no hit,therefore flag2=1  (still have 1 hit)
- Item2 is predicted at x3 therefore flag3=2
- In column x4 i have no hit therefore flag4=2 (still have 2 hits)
- Item4 is predicted at x5 therefore flag5=3

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the unique Measure1 and Measure2 for each ID

Comment: @akrun Measure 1 and Measure 2 is the same for each row under same ID so when aggregated to ID level one row will remain

Comment: Try `df3 <- df2[5:(ncol(df2)-1)];
i1 <- df2$XO[row(df3)]==df3;cumsum(colSums(i1))`

Comment: nope, it doesnt create the columns flag1-flag5

Comment: This is what I get as output `X1 x2 x3 x4  x 
 1  1  2  2  3`

Comment: I have a doubt, suppose if you have flag like `1, 3, 3`, what would be the expected

Comment: then flag3 would be 3 since i would have hit the three products up to that point, and flag4&flag5 would be 3 as well

Comment: Suppose you want it to be based on the 'ID" group, `t(apply(rowsum(+(i1), group=df2$ID)!=0, 1, cumsum))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92477/discussion-between-arko21-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a subset of the dataset i.e. columns X1 to x ('df3').  After making the lengths same between the 'XO' and 'df3', compare to create the logical matrix ('i1'), then use `rowsum` grouped by 'ID' to get the `sum` of each column, convert again to logical (`!=0`), get the `cumsum` of each row using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, transpose (`t`) and `cbind` with the `unique` elements of first 3 columns of 'df2'.

```
df3 <- df2[5:(ncol(df2)-1)]
i1 <- df2$XO[row(df3)]==df3
cbind(unique(df2[1:3]),
      t(apply(rowsum(+(i1), group=df2$ID)!=0, 1, cumsum)))
#          ID Measure1 Measure2 X1 x2 x3 x4 x
#1 Customer 1       30        2  1  1  2  2 3
#4 Customer 2       32        4  0  1  2  2 2
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("Customer 1", "Customer 1", "Customer 1", 
"Customer 2", "Customer 2", "Customer 2"), Measure1 = c(30L, 
30L, 30L, 32L, 32L, 32L), Measure2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), XO = c("item1", "item2", "item4", "item1", "item5", "item7"
), X1 = c("item1", "item1", "item1", "item5", "item1", "item1"
), x2 = c("item5", "item5", "item5", "item1", "item5", "item5"
), x3 = c("item2", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item7"
), x4 = c("item12", "item12", "item12", "item12", "item12", "item12"
), x = c("item4", "item4", "item4", "item4", "item4", "item4"
), Flag = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("ID", "Measure1", 
"Measure2", "XO", "X1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x", "Flag"), class = "data.frame",
        row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Could the NAs be treated like no hit? because otherwise it will return NA

Comment: @ArKo21  Let me try with NA

Comment: @ArKo21  Can you check if  `i1[is.na(i1)] <- FALSE` before the `cbind` works

Comment: i2<-replace(i1, is.na(i1), FALSE) i used this just to be on the safe side, thank you for your help